# Facing issue with cross platform notifications with quickblox

Tags: android, ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, quickblox

I have integrated **push notifications** with **quichkblox SDK** with **FCM**, same is done in iOS app. But when the **iOS app is in background or killed** then notification sent from android is **not received at iOS end**. What could be the reason behind this???

Comment: This seems to be a custom issue, please contact [QuickBlox Support](https://assist.quickblox.com/index.php?/Tickets/Submit) for assistance

Comment: Hello, have you resolved this issue? I am also facing this issue.

Comment: @KiranK I have removed Quickblox from my app now. It was giving many issues and users were reporting complants

Comment: @kartikavij  Oh then now which SDK you have integrated into your application.

Comment: I am using sockets now